# BootstrapUI: Popover cut off by page end

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

These are AngularUI Bootstrap popovers, which are written in Angular instead of jQuery.

I have a popover in a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/H1aeQu9ifBe0zyMzC845?p=preview) that is working, but it's positioning is messed up.  It is being cut in half by the page.

[image]

When I inspect the popover's CSS, I see some code which doesn't make any sense to me.  I understand what it's doing, but where are these `element.style` properties coming from?  They seem to be the problem.

```
element.style {
  top: -139px;
  left: 112px;
  display: block;
}

.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1060;
  display: none;
  max-width: 276px;
  padding: 1px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: left;
  text-align: start;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-break: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: normal;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  line-break: auto;
}
```

There isn't even a scroll option available.  Is there a way to position a popover so that the entirety of it appears on the page, regardless of where the button is?

Answer (score 1):

In the element where you whant your popover displayed, add the following directive:

`popover-append-to-body="true"`

Like this:

```
<small popover="{{form.descripcion}}" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-append-to-body="true">
    [{{form.status}}]
</small>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element styling is set in the [source](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L136-L141) of UI Bootstrap in the `tooltip` section.

Tooltips and popovers are not meant to store that much data which is why they just center it over the element that it is attached to.

---

***EDIT***

For this specific example you can add this CSS:

```
.popover-parent + .popover {
    top: 0 !important;
}

.popover-parent + .popover .arrow {
    top: 15px !important;
}
```

The most dynamic way would be to hook into the event that shows the tooltip and calculate the position of the popover then.

Comment: Is there a way to override those styles in CSS, or would the JS have to be edited?